# Forms.Context does not exist In xamarin froms HybridWebView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hello I am working on a Xamarin forms portable project using the .net standard I have a page in my app the needs to load html content locally. when I go to run the app on a android device the build fails and give's me this error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Context' does not exist in
>   the namespace 'AppName.Forms' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

[Here's the example i'm going off of](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/HybridWebView)

here's the class i'm getting the error on:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using AppName.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Android.Webkit;
using System.ComponentModel;
using AppName.Forms;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HybridWebView), typeof(AppName.Droid.HybridWebViewRenderer))]

namespace AppName.Droid
{
    public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, Android.Webkit.WebView>
    {
        const string JavaScriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(data){jsBridge.invokeAction(data);}";

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
                Control.Settings.DisplayZoomControls = true;
            }
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                                                   //               |
                                                   //Error is here \|/
                var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(Forms.Context);  
                webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                SetNativeControl(webView);
                Control.Settings.DomStorageEnabled = true;
            }
            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                Control.RemoveJavascriptInterface("jsBridge");
                var hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HybridWebView;
                hybridWebView.Cleanup();
            }
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge(this), "jsBridge");
                Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("file:///android_asset/Content/{0}", Element.Uri));
                InjectJS(JavaScriptFunction);
            }
        }

        void InjectJS(string script)
        {
            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.LoadUrl(string.Format("javascript: {0}", script));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

any help would be amazing!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is using AppName.Forms ? Looks like you are overriding "Forms" somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Like Yuri already stated in the comments; there is some ambiguity between you namespaces. Because it is probably too much work to refactor all that, the easiest would be to spell out the full namespace in this case.

Change your code to `var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(Xamarin.Forms.Context);`

Comment: I would rather dig and find where the problem is. It will bite you in many places :-)

Comment: The problem is obvious, no digging required. I see `using AppName.Forms;` in the list. So it tries to look in the wrong namespace which is also called Forms. You can (and should) refractor that out, but it's a pain in the ass depending on how big your app is.

Comment: Agree but my point is that I think it's worth refactoring especially if VS will do all that for you.